# How export Testcase from KIWI TCMS by use API?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I am solving in the company how to export saved test cases from kiwi to xls file. I just found how to import data (https://gist.github.com/atodorov/f5aed028b6f254d97bcaf93453abe8d2).

Didn't you solve someone similar problem here, how to export test cases from kiwi? A specific example would help me .. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

https://tcms-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms_api.html?highlight=rpc_client%20exec%20testcase

```
from tcms_api import TCMS

rpc_client = TCMS()

for test_case in rpc_client.exec.TestCase.filter({'pk': 46490}):
    print(test_case)
```

Instead of printing the test_case, just save it into XLS via some python library.

Comment: Maybe you can answer me to my next question... see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56848500/export-testcases-from-kiwi-tcms-by-python-script-does-not-work