# Export testcases from KIWI TCMS by python script does not work

Tags: python, kiwi-tcms

I have script for export some Testcases from KIWI TCMS system. Problem is, that script does not work. Script does not return anything. 
And second questions. What does it mean this: {'pk': 46490}
Is it some filtr?

```
--------------------------------------- 
from tcms_api import TCMS
rpc_client = TCMS()
for test_case in rpc_client.exec.TestCase.filter({'pk': 46490}):
    print(test_case) 
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: or I need some specific code before of script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How export Testcase from KIWI TCMS by use API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627818/how-export-testcase-from-kiwi-tcms-by-use-api)